# Can piece of R code influence random numbers in foreach output?

Tags: r, random, foreach, doparallel

I run a simulation using `foreach` and `doParallel` and struggling with random numbers (named `random` in the code).

In a nutshell: I simulate a football league, randomly generating winners of all the matches and corresponding results. In `dt_base` no match was played, in `dt_ex1` and `dt_ex2` results of 4 matches are known already. All unknown results should be simulated.

In the *League Simulation Code* at the bottom of this post I set 1000 simulations, split into 100 chunks (the forloop is used to send data to PostgreSQL and reduce RAM usage in the full code I use). **I expect all the random numbers to be different (don't even insist on reproducible results).**

**1. When running the code as given**, one should achieve the goal of all different random numbers.

```
> # ====== Distinct Random Numbers ======
> length(unique(out$random))                              # expectation: 22000
[1] 22000
> length(unique(out$random[out$part == "base"]))          # expectation: 10000
[1] 10000
> length(unique(out$random[out$part == "dt_ex1"]))        # expectation: 6000
[1] 6000
> length(unique(out$random[out$part == "dt_ex2"]))        # expectation: 6000
[1] 6000
```

**2. Now please uncomment the pieces of code which assigns the final score** `*[tmp_sim] = 3` (should be lines 60,61,67,68 with `!!!` on them) and run it again.

```
> # ====== Distinct Random Numbers ======
> length(unique(out$random))                              # expectation: 22000
[1] 10360
> length(unique(out$random[out$part == "base"]))          # expectation: 10000
[1] 10000
> length(unique(out$random[out$part == "dt_ex1"]))        # expectation: 6000
[1] 180
> length(unique(out$random[out$part == "dt_ex2"]))        # expectation: 6000
[1] 180
```

That is when it gets messed up and it doesn't make sense to me. `random` inside `iter` is always the same for `dt_ex1` and `dt_ex2` when adding couple of numbers into these dataframes.

Are you experiencing the same effect? Any idea what is going on please?

I tried R versions 3.5.3 and 3.6.3. Also tried `doRNG` package. Always the same problem.

#### League Simulation Code

```
# League Simulation
rm(list = ls())
set.seed(666)
cat("\014")
library(sqldf)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

# ====== User Functions ======
comb4 = function(x, ...) { #function for combining foreach output
  Map(rbind, x, ...)
}

# ====== Data Preparation ======
dt_base = data.frame(id = 1:10,
                  part = rep("base",10),
                  random = NA)

dt_ex1 = data.frame(id = 1:10,
                         part = rep("dt_ex1",10),
                         HG = c(1,3,6,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA),  # Home Goals
                         AG = c(1,3,6,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA),  # Away Goals
                         random = NA)

dt_ex2 = data.frame(id = 1:10,
                            part = rep("dt_ex2",10),
                         HG = c(1,3,6,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA),  # Home Goals
                         AG = c(1,3,6,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA),  # Away Goals
                         random = NA)

# ====== Set Parallel Computing ======
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cl = makeCluster(3, outfile = "")
registerDoParallel(cl)

# ====== SIMULATION ======
nsim = 1000                # number of simulations
iterChunk = 100            # split nsim into this many chunks
out = data.frame()    # prepare output DF
for(iter in 1:ceiling(nsim/iterChunk)){
  strt = Sys.time()
  
  out_iter = 
    foreach(i = 1:iterChunk, .combine = comb4, .multicombine = TRUE, .maxcombine = 100000, .inorder = FALSE, .verbose = FALSE,
            .packages = c("plyr", "dplyr", "sqldf")) %dopar% {
              
              ## PART 1
              # simulation number
              id_sim = iterChunk * (iter - 1) + i
              
              # First random numbers set
              dt_base[,"random"] = runif(nrow(dt_base))
              
              
              ## PART 2
              tmp_sim = is.na(dt_ex1$HG) # no results yet
              dt_ex1$random[tmp_sim] = runif(sum(tmp_sim))
              # dt_ex1$HG[tmp_sim] = 3   # !!!
              # dt_ex1$AG[tmp_sim] = 3   # !!!
              
              
              ## PART 3
              tmp_sim = is.na(dt_ex2$HG) # no results yet
              dt_ex2$random[tmp_sim] = runif(sum(tmp_sim))
              # dt_ex2$HG[tmp_sim] = 3   # !!!
              # dt_ex2$AG[tmp_sim] = 3   # !!!
              
              
              # ---- Save Results
              zapasy = rbind.data.frame(dt_base[,c("id","part","random")],
                                        dt_ex1[,c("id","part","random")]
                                        ,dt_ex2[,c("id","part","random")]
              )
              zapasy$id_sim = id_sim
              zapasy$iter = iter
              zapasy$i = i
              
              out_i = list(zapasy = zapasy)
              
              print(Sys.time())
              return(out_i)
            }#i;sim_forcycle
  
  out = rbind.data.frame(out,subset(out_iter$zapasy, !is.na(random)))
  
  fnsh = Sys.time()
  cat(" [",iter,"] ",fnsh - strt, sep = "")
  
}#iter


# ====== Distinct Random Numbers ======
length(unique(out$random))                              # expectation: 22000
length(unique(out$random[out$part == "base"]))          # expectation: 10000
length(unique(out$random[out$part == "dt_ex1"]))        # expectation: 6000
length(unique(out$random[out$part == "dt_ex2"]))        # expectation: 6000


# ====== Stop Parallel Computing ======
stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 1):

The random generator used by R (including by `set.seed` and `runif`) is global and applies to the whole application.

It appears that your problem is happening because the generator's access is shared between parallel processes, but is not synchronized between these processes (that is, it's not "thread safe"), so that each process has its own view of the generator's state (so that, as a result, different processes can draw exactly the same random numbers due to this unsynchronized access).  Instead, you should give each parallel process (each simulation in this case) its own random generator that's not shared between processes, and [seed each process](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Seeding_Multiple_Processes) (or simulation) accordingly.

Multithreading is one of the [many issues to consider](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Ensuring_Reproducibility) when reproducible "random" numbers are something you care about.

---

As it turns out, the underlying issue is caused more by *data frames* being shared among processes, rather than R's global RNG.  See this question [Multithread computation with R: how to get all different random numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758637/multithread-computation-with-r-how-to-get-all-different-random-numbers) .

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I am aware of what you are saying. However it is this little change in code (not influencing random number generator) that makes the difference. I don't need the results to be reproducible. I tried the doRNG package which controls seeds among threads, without success. Will give it a one more try though. It seems like the only way to get over this, because these results don't make sense, really.